# Collapsing Toolbar Layout expand on click event and not on scroll

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a simple toolbar with a info icon item on the right.
When click on the item I would like to expand the toolbar with an animation. With a new view and a FAB button.
Like the Textra SMS is doing.

When clicking outside the expanded toolbar, I want to colapse the toolbar.

I looking how can I handle this with CollapsingToolbarLayout? Is it possible?
All the example I find on the web are collapsing/Expanding with the scroll of the the view (Recyclerview, Scrollview etc...). But I don't want my toolbar to move when scrolling my view.

It is a good way to use CollapsingToolbarLayout? or do I need to do it all by myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CollapsingToolbarLayout` seems perfectly fine for that purpose (and I actually believe it would make your layout look much better than one in the `Textra SMS` app).

You will need few things:

1. A way to disable `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. The best way in my opinion (at least the best I found so far) is to use a custom `CoordinatorLayout` instead of the regular `CoordinatorLayout`.

   ```
   public class DisableableCoordinatorLayout extends CoordinatorLayout {
       private boolean mPassScrolling = true;

       public DisableableCoordinatorLayout(Context context) {
           super(context);
       }

       public DisableableCoordinatorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
       }

       public DisableableCoordinatorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onStartNestedScroll(View child, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
           return mPassScrolling && super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, nestedScrollAxes);
       }

       public void setPassScrolling(boolean passScrolling) {
           mPassScrolling = passScrolling;
       }
   }
   ```
2. You need to actually disable your `CollapsingToolbarLayout` (you don't want your `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to react to scrolls anymore):

   ```
   mDisableableCoordinatorLayout.setPassScrolling(false);
   ```
3. You need to use your `AppBarLayout` to expand the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` onOptionsMenu item click

   ```
   mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true);
   ```
4. You also need to use the `AppBarLayout` to collapse the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` on click outside (implement click outside in any way you feel like)

   ```
   mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true);
   ```